# Informix - update SET column with results from a subselect

Tags: sql, informix

I have a table with a collection column. I want to do a subselect which returns several integers and put the result in that collection column, however I can't find a syntax to do it through SQL. I did it by writing an SQL procedure which does the same thing (put results of SELECT in SET variable and return variable), however I'm trying to do the same without functions. Can it be done?

First, I create a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE table1 (
  id INTEGER
, col2 SET(INT NOT NULL)
)
```

Then I fill it with test data:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO table1 (id) VALUES (2);
```

And now this works:

```
UPDATE table1 SET col2 = SET{1,2};
```

...but I'm trying to do this and it doesn't work:

```
UPDATE table1 SET col2 = (SELECT id FROM table1) WHERE id = 1;
```

It returns this error:

```
[Error Code: -9632, SQL State: IX000]  Value does not match the type of column (col2).
```

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating SET types in pure SQL is a pain.

Your UPDATE is trying to assign an INTEGER to a SET OF INTEGER, and the error says "you can't do that".

You should be able to do:

```
UPDATE table1
   SET col2 = SET { (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id = 1) }
 WHERE id = 1;
```

However, I'm not sure what the correct modification is to get more than one value into the set; the inner WHERE is not there idly.

Comment: Yes, that works for one value; it also works if I write subselect for every value like this: UPDATE table1 SET col2 = SET { (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id = 1), (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id = 2) } WHERE id = 1; ... however this is obviously not the solution I need. :)

Comment: @Domchi: OK - well, I have not done enough with sets to know what the answer is, and I'm not sure exactly what you really want to do since transferring an integer ID into a singleton set is not very interesting to my way of thinking.

Comment: I'm trying to insert several integer IDs into a set; integers are the output of an unrelated subselect. In this simplified example, I'm trying to convert the result of this subselect into a set: "SELECT id FROM table1" (which returns two values, 1 and 2). The problem is that I don't know how many integers will the subselect return, but definitely not just one.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using **MULTISET** and **ITEM** keyword
the following example will work:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE table1 (
  id INTEGER
  ,col2 MULTISET(INT NOT NULL)
);

INSERT INTO table1 (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO table1 (id) VALUES (2);

UPDATE table1 SET col2 = MULTISET{1,2};

UPDATE table1
   SET col2 = MULTISET(SELECT ITEM id FROM table1)
WHERE id = 1;
```

Be aware of the differences between SET and MULTISET

```
select set{1,2,1,3,1} from systables where tabid=1;
```

returns SET{1,2,3}

```
select multiset{1,2,1,3,1} from systables where tabid=1;
```

returns MULTISET{1,2,1,3,1}